# Get index values for an array to print in value attribute for radio buttons

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, indexing

**Problem:**

To get the index values of an array to print accordingly in value attribute of radio buttons.

**The array $_SESSION['items']:**

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [category] => 2
            [question] => Array
                (
                    [6] => Källorna refereras separat
                    [7] => Vissa försök till sammanbindning
                    [8] => En del sammanfattningar
                    [9] => Olika forskningslinjer jämförs och sammanfattas
                    [10] => Kontraster, jämförelser, sammanfattningar; centrala likheter och skillnader framhävs
                )

            [title] => Integration av källorna
        )
)
```

**I have a PHP function that looks like this:**

```
function itemsLayout ($array)
{   
    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($array['question']); $i++)
    {

        $form .= '<input type="radio" name="'.$array['category'].'" id="'.$array['category'].'" value="INDEX VALUE FOR QUESTION ARRAY HERE">';
    }

    return $form;
}
```

**PHP code:**

I get the index by using the following:

```
$key = key($_SESSION['items']);
$current = $_SESSION['items'][$key];
```

**And I print the first index by using:**

```
echo itemsLayout($current);
```

**Question:**

How do I get the index values 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 to print in the value attribute for each radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the foreach loop 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

and I think the sintax was

```
foreach ($x as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . "<br />";
}
```

instead of for ($i = 1; $i <= count($array['question']); $i++)

LE: a better link is this one http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($question as $q) {
  $form .= sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%d" id="%d", value="%s">', $array['category'], $array['category'], $q);
}
```